# In Django rest framework, can I modify serializer instead of accepting 2 lists to accept a list of objects containing them

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to modify the way I want to accept data from endpoints without modifying the model defined for it. Hence I want to modify the serializer. I am not sure how should I redefine it.

I have a serializer defined as

```py
class AssetWorkorderSerializer(MaxenBaseSerializer):
    id = ReadOnlyField()
    assets = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=False,
        allow_null=False,
        queryset=models.Asset.objects.all(),
    )
    assignee = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=False, read_only=False, allow_null=True, queryset=User.objects.all()
    )
    checklists = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, read_only=False, queryset=Checklist.objects.all()
    )
    assigned_by = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=False, queryset=User.objects.all())
    deadline = ReadOnlyField()
    overdue = ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.AssetWorkorder
        fields = "__all__"
```

So objects accepted are:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "https://<some-url>/assetworkorders/29/",
            "id": 29,
            "assets": [
                292,
                293
            ],
            "assignee": 33,
            "checklists": [
                7,
                8,
                9
            ],
            "assigned_by": 32,
            "deadline": "2022-03-31",
            "overdue": true,
            "created": "2022-03-31T03:52:59.123745Z",
            "updated": "2022-03-31T17:18:49.599963Z",
            "name": "Service HVACs",
            "description": "Service HVACs",
            "status": "OP",
            "priority": "LO",
            "duedate": "2022-03-31",
            "scheduleddate": "2022-03-30",
            "notifications_enabled": false
        },
    ]
}
```

Instead I want to accept like this:

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "https://<some-url>/assetworkorders/29/",
            "id": 29,
            "assetChecklist": [
                {"asset": 292, "checklists": [7,8]},
                {"asset": 293, "checklists": [8,9]},
            ],
            "assignee": 33,
            "assigned_by": 32,
            "deadline": "2022-03-31",
            "overdue": true,
            "created": "2022-03-31T03:52:59.123745Z",
            "updated": "2022-03-31T17:18:49.599963Z",
            "name": "Service HVACs",
            "description": "Service HVACs",
            "status": "OP",
            "priority": "LO",
            "duedate": "2022-03-31",
            "scheduleddate": "2022-03-30",
            "notifications_enabled": false
        },
    ]
}
```

Without modifying model.

I am already modifying create method, I will overwrite it again to save data as it is.

Other models are defined as:

```py
class AssetWorkorder(MaxenBaseModel):
    @property
    def organizationsite_name(self):
        return self.assets[0].organizationsite.organization.name

    assets = models.ManyToManyField("Asset", verbose_name="Assets")
    name = models.CharField("Name", blank=False, max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(
        "Description", null=True, blank=True, max_length=2048
    )

    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        OPEN = "OP", "Open"
        INPROGRESS = "IP", "In progress"
        BLOCKED = "BL", "Blocked"
        COMPLETED = "CO", "Completed"

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.OPEN)

    class Priority(models.TextChoices):
        LOW = "LO", "Low"
        NORMAL = "NO", "Normal"
        HIGH = "HI", "High"
        URGENT = "UR", "Urgent"

    priority = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=Priority.choices, default=Priority.NORMAL
    )

    duedate = models.DateField("Due date", editable=True, null=True)
    scheduleddate = models.DateField(
        "Scheduled date", editable=True, null=True)

    assigned_by = models.ForeignKey(
        "auth.User", help_text="", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="assigned_by"
    )
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(
        "auth.User",
        help_text="",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="assignee",
        null=True,
    )

    @property
    def deadline(self):
        """
        Deadline is the scheduled date if this one is upcoming, otherwise,
        the deadline is the due date.
        """
        if self.duedate and self.scheduleddate:
            return (
                self.scheduleddate
                if self.scheduleddate >= timezone.now().date()
                else self.duedate
            )
        else:
            return self.duedate or self.scheduleddate

    @property
    def overdue(self) -> bool:
        return self.deadline == self.duedate

    notifications_enabled = models.BooleanField(
        "Enable notifications", default=False)

    checklists = ManyToManyField("Checklist", through="WorkorderChecklist")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
        verbose_name = "Workorder (class: AssetWorkorder)"
        verbose_name_plural = "Workorders (class: AssetWorkorder)"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AssetChecklist(MaxenBaseModel):
    asset = models.ForeignKey("Asset", null=False,
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    checklist = models.ForeignKey("Checklist", null=False,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    verbose_name = "AssetChecklist"
    verbose_name_plural = "AssetChecklists"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.asset.name + " <-> " + self.checklist.name

class Asset(MaxenBaseModel):
    """
    Assets can be just about anything, from buildings to machines or individual
    components of a system such as sensors or controllers. Assets are an abstract
    concept enabling hierarchical organization pf elements by relating them through
    parent/child relationships or semantic relationships.

    NOTE:
        Assets having both an AssetCategory and an AssetType fk AND an AssetType having
        its own AssetCategory fk is a bit funky but the OG model was built that way as
        well.
    """

    name = models.CharField("Asset name", max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(
        "Description", max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    organizationsite = models.ForeignKey(
        "OrganizationSite",
        verbose_name="Organization site",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    thumbnail2 = models.ImageField(
        "thumbnail2", storage=ThumbnailStorage, blank=True, null=True
    )

    # FIXME: Remove once the migration to thumbnail2 is done
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        "thumbnail",
        upload_to="s3temp",
        max_length=1024,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="Thumbnail image for the asset",
    )

    assetcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        "AssetCategory",
        verbose_name="Asset category",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    assettype = ChainedForeignKey(
        AssetType,
        chained_field="assetcategory",
        chained_model_field="assetcategory",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name="Asset type",
        help_text="Linked type",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    organizationcontacts = models.ManyToManyField(
        "OrganizationContact",
        verbose_name="Organization category",
        blank=True,
    )

    graph = models.JSONField(
        "Graph",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="Graph representation cache, update on save of an assetrelationship "
        "or an asset",
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
        verbose_name = "Asset"
        verbose_name_plural = "Assets"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def get_visible_for_user(cls, user: User) -> QuerySet:
        exposed_organizationsites = OrganizationSite.get_visible_for_user(user)
        return cls.objects.filter(organizationsite__in=exposed_organizationsites)

    def update_graph(self):

        G = nx.Graph()

        nodes = Asset.objects.filter(organizationsite=self.organizationsite)
        for n in nodes:
            G.add_node(n.id)

        edges = AssetRelationship.objects.filter(
            Q(assetA__organizationsite=self.organizationsite)
            | Q(assetB__organizationsite=self.organizationsite)
        )
        for e in edges:
            G.add_edge(e.assetA.id, e.assetB.id)

        assets_connected_to = node_connected_component(G, self.id)

        # build vizjs json graph
        nodes = []
        edges = []
        for a in assets_connected_to:
            asset = Asset.objects.filter(id=a).get()
            node = {
                "id": asset.id,
                "label": asset.name,
                "group": "",
                "meta": {
                    "asset_displayname": asset.name,
                    "asset_type": asset.assettype.name
                    if asset.assettype is not None
                    else "",
                    "asset_category": asset.assetcategory.name
                    if asset.assetcategory is not None
                    else "",
                },
            }
            nodes.append(node)

        relationships = AssetRelationship.objects.filter(
            Q(assetA__in=list(assets_connected_to))
            | Q(assetB__in=list(assets_connected_to))
        ).distinct()
        for r in relationships:
            edge = {
                "from": r.assetA.id,
                "to": r.assetB.id,
                "label": r.relationshiptype.name,
                "meta": {
                    "link_id": r.id,
                    "link_name": r.assetA.name
                    + " "
                    + r.relationshiptype.name
                    + " "
                    + r.assetB.name,
                    "link_type": r.relationshiptype.name,
                },
            }
            edges.append(edge)

        graph = {"nodes": nodes, "edges": edges}
        self.graph = graph

class Checklist(MaxenBaseModel):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        "Organization", verbose_name="Organization", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField("Checklist Name", max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(
        "Description", max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
        verbose_name = "Checklist"
        verbose_name_plural = "Checklists"
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['organization', 'name'], name='unique_organization_name_combination'
            )
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MaxenBaseModel(models.Model):
    """
    Base model with timestamps
    """

    created = models.DateTimeField(
        "Created on",
        auto_now_add=True,
        editable=False,
        help_text="This field is autopopulated by the platform and represents the"
        " creation timestamp of the object",
    )
    updated = models.DateTimeField(
        "Updated on",
        auto_now=True,
        editable=False,
        help_text="This field is autopopulated by the platform and represents the"
        " object's last update's timestamp",
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True  # add this to base models so it doesn't get migrated
```

Comment: Can you please add `AssetWorkorder`, `Asset`, and `Checklist` model here?

Comment: I have edited question to add the asked models.

Comment: Please see how to write a [mre], also see [ask]. Your question is not very clear on exactly what you want, one can guess by comparing the expected and actual results but even those aren't _minimal_.